# Feature detection по обнаружению одинаковых признаков на одном фото

Tags: python, opencv

Feature detection ,как я понимаю, нацелен на  обнаружение схожих признаков на разных изображениях
[image: Пример Feature detection]
Мне-же нужно найти одинаковые признаки на одном изображении(если бы я в Paint просто скопировал и перенес какой-то элемент изображения).
Есть ли такая возможность на Python в Opencv?
Если нет, то что можно использовать для этой задачи и где найти информацию?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Корреляционно-экстремальные методы (поиск шаблона в области интереса). Если есть возможность отсегментировать объект - можно рассчитать различные инвариантные к повороту и масштабу дескрипторы - моменты Зернике, Ху и т.д. Ну и тот же SIFT и прочие уголковые признаки никто не отменял.

Comment: Вам стоит почитать книги по теории распознавания образов - начните с Гонсалес, Вудс.

Comment: Благодарю, особенно за книгу! Нашел статью оставлю ее здесь если вдруг кто наткнется на туже проблему https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/copy-move-forgery-detection-using-sift-and-dbscan-clustering-4a179c36293e
Но могу я задать вам буквально 2 вопроса?
1) Под сегментацией вы имели ввиду свертку с выходом в ЧБ маску?
2) Если да то какая архитектура большее подходит для такой задачи?

Comment: Свертку, пороговую обработку, кластеризацию. Да, на выходе получается бинарное или маскированное изображение с пронумерованными масками (см. bw label). Что значит архитектура? Какой фреймворк? Да те же OpenCV, Matlab Image Processing Toolbox.

Comment: Использовал tenserflow и вот такую архитектуру, добавил картинку к вопросу, но я так понимаю это лишнее, поскольку все можно было сделать через cv2

Comment: Ну Вы показываете какую-то узкоспециализированную нейросеть, которая из спутниковых снимков делает топографическую карту. Для Вашей задачи с фрагментом в Paint это явно избыточно.

Comment: Благодарю за помощь)